# shortcode which is introduced into entry the blog, and appears in side bar

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, filters, shortcode

I have the following shortcode plugin, it works perfectly, nothing more I want to put you in the blog and appear in the sidebar, how I can accomplish this?

I want not put a widget in the sidebar, because I want to work for the specified entry and not all entries.

```
<?php

add_shortcode('myshorcode', 'myshorcodeInblogentry');

function myshorcodeInblogentry($atts){
    ob_start();
    extract( shortcode_atts( array (
        'posts' => '',
        'artist' => '',
    ), $atts ) );

    $options = array( 
        'posts_per_page' => $posts,
        'post_type' => array (
            'post' => 'post',
        ),
        'meta_value' => $artist
    ); 

    $products = new WP_Query( $options );
    if( $products->have_posts() ) {
      while( $products->have_posts() ) {
        $products->the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="relacional">
          <h5><?php the_title() ?></h5>
          <div class="featured-image">
         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); ?></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php
return ob_get_clean();
      }
    }
    else {
      echo 'Oh ohm no productos!';
    }
}

?>
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

1. At the end of your function return the output [as described in the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Output).

   return ob_get_clean();
2. Add the [myshorcode] shortcode to a **text widget**. By default, widgets are not rendered in text widgets so make sure you add this snippet to your plugin:

   add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');

Comment: I am edit code add "return ob_get_clean();" and work fine in my widget text i write "<?php
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );
?>" but not in the widget content is printed output shortcode, and continues printing within the blog entry content, I want the shortcode to put inside the body content, appears in my widget, very thanks

Comment: You have to write the name of the shortcode, like [myshortcode], into a text widget.